# asp:GridView showes nothing (empty GridView)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I write interface in asp.net. I'am use `<asp:GridView>` component and it showes nothing. I tried to add it by code and by designer, but when i debug it, the div, that should contain GV's code, is empty (I saw that by Google Chrome's Developer's tools).

I'm tried to use this

`<EmptyDataTemplate>ITemplate</EmptyDataTemplate>`,

but it gives same result. Maybe i don't understand something important.

Comment: post your gridview aspx code and codebehind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your `GridView` with `null`.

```
GridView.DataSource = null;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where should i do that? in script or in aspx code part?